# Is the "\$\small o\$" in \$r_o\$ short for output or number 0?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, modeling, small-signal

You usually see *r<sub>o</sub>* in the small-signal models of BJTs or MOSFETs like this.

I'm curious if the "o" there is short for "output" or just the number zero? I think I saw people reading it both ways.

[image]

Comment: Short for "output" I believe. That's how I 'read' it, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a BJT, \$R_O\$ or \$r_O\$ refers to the output resistance and the character in question is the letter "O". Its input equivalent resistance is termed \$R_I\$ or \$r_I\$ and is usually appended with an "E" for a common emitter BJT i.e. \$R_{IE}\$ or \$r_{IE}\$.

Capital letters are optional I believe.